# convert docx to html while keeping content controls tags and metadata

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, docx

I have `docx` documents with content control fields that I populate programatically. I would like to convert these Word documents to HTML while maintaining the content control tags and its metadata. When I open these Word documents and click on "Save As", "Web Page (.html)", the resulting HTML produces this:

```
<span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif">
  <w:Sdt
    DocPart="80CD2684909242928B858862BDF7732B"
    Text="t"
    Title="full_name"
    SdtTag="full_name"
    ID="1185485261"
    >
      David Warner Roy
  </w:Sdt>
  <span style="mso-tab-count: 2"></span>
</span>
```

Online APIs like [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/) or open source ones like [mammoth.js](https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js/) all strip out the content control handles completely. I've tried out many online APIs and GitHub libraries that I could find.

Microsoft seems to provide no such capability as well.

Anyone have any ideas or know of any libraries I can use?

---

For context, I want to simulate editable Word documents in a website, so that I can capture user input tagged with the content control metadata, like "full_name" in the sample code above. I would like to replace the `<w:Sdt>` tags in the HTML with `input` and tag them with the `SdtTag` so that when a user makes changes, I know which fields are changed and then I can regenerate the actual Word document.

Comment: «I would like to convert these Word documents to HTML while maintaining the content control tags and its metadata» Not going to happen.

Comment: You have the `html` version of the document. Does it looks (more or less) like the original `docx` file when you open it in the browser? If that´s the case, probably you have a good start to build your own library, and parse the file into what you need, just by replacing the tags it has for what you need, and back. What about using something like a mapper, that crawls the content in the file before displaying it, and replaces the words/tags it finds.